# Excel number conversion to scientific notation string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using TEXT function to convert number to the string in scientific notation.

I need to be able to convert my number to a specific number of digits before E+
For example, I need to convert

- 5000 to 5E+3
- 5000 to 50E+2
- 5000 to 500E+1
- etc.

But I am getting different results

- TEXT(5000, "0E+0") gives 5E+3 As expected
- TEXT(5000, "00E+0") gives 50E+2 As expected
- TEXT(5000, "000E+0") gives 005E+3 NOT As expected

Why last one did not work and how to make it working?

Comment: Actually `5E+3` is `5*10^3` and `50E+2` is `50*10^2` But `500E+1` is `500*10^1`   and any single formula can't convert `5000` in `500E+1` !!

Comment: You are right about the numbers "`5E+3` is `5*10^3` and `50E+2` is `50*10^2` But `500E+1` is `500*10^1`". But it is all the same number which is 5000. The question is why excel works fine for first and second and does not work for the third one.

Comment: excel works mathematically,,, and if you write `=5*100^1` you get `500` but if write this `=TEXT(5*100^1,"000E+0")` get `500E+0`. And to get `5000` you need to write `=50*100^1` .

Comment: This question is not about mathematical calculation, but it is about the number to string conversion. The question is "Why excel function TEXT does not work as expected and how to fix it or is there any workaround?"

I do not have `100^1` anywhere, where did you get it? I only operate with `10^N`. also if I type in excel 500e+1 I am getting 5000. I do not understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I use number mantissa and order of magnitude.
so the formula is like this

if 5000 in A1, then `=A1/10^INT(LOG(A1)) & "E+" & INT(LOG(A1))` gives 5E+3

if 5000 in A2, then `=10*A2/10^INT(LOG(A2)) & "E+" & (INT(LOG(A2))-1)` gives 50E+2

if 5000 in A3, then `=100*A3/10^INT(LOG(A3)) & "E+" & (INT(LOG(A3))-2)` gives 500E+1

Answer (score -1):

Try this Custom number format:

```
##0E+0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. Does it work for you? Did you manage to convert 5000 to 500E+1?